# Style to make RadioButtons look like ToggleButtons, but recolored?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've made a custom radioButton style to make my buttons look like ToggleButtons. They work, but my triggers don't seem to apply to the buttons.
My code:

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <ToggleButton Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                              IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                            <ToggleButton.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF161717"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGreen"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF161717"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ToggleButton.Style>
                        </ToggleButton>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

The styling works, but the trigger colors don't get applied.

EDIT: Found a solution:
Image Source="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not wrap a `ToggleButton` into a `RadioButton`. That's wrong. Apart from the overhead it will only introduce annoying layout issues like focus handling or event handling etc. - and, like in your case, layout issue like visual states or triggers don't modify the layout as expected.
Instead override the default `ControlTemplate` and adjust the layout to adapt to the look and feel of a `ToggleButton`. The simplest case is to copy the `ControlTemplate` of the `ToggleButton`.

You can find example styles and templates at [Microsoft Docs: Control Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#in-this-section) or extract them using the XAML designer of Visual Studio or Blend.

A restyled `RadioButton` that looks like a `ToggleButton` could look as follows:

```xml
<Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
          Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
          Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
          Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="Padding"
          Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Border x:Name="border"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
          <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                            Focusable="False"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted"
                    Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    TargetName="border"
                    Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                    Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    TargetName="border"
                    Value="{x:Static Brushes.CornflowerBlue}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    TargetName="border"
                    Value="{x:Static Brushes.CornflowerBlue}" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                    Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    TargetName="border"
                    Value="{x:Static Brushes.DarkBlue}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    TargetName="border"
                    Value="{x:Static Brushes.Black}" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                    Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    TargetName="border"
                    Value="{x:Static Brushes.Gray}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    TargetName="border"
                    Value="{x:Static Brushes.DarkGray}" />
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                    TargetName="contentPresenter"
                    Value="{x:Static Brushes.DarkGray}" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works better than my solution!